# Swift - How do you tell when a NSScrollView starts to scroll?

Tags: swift, macos, nsscrollview

Is there a way in Swift to tell when a NSScrollView has begun scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observer that listens to the `NSScrollViewWillStartLiveScrollNotification` [[1]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSScrollViewDidLiveScrollNotification)

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClass.YourFunctionName), name: NSScrollViewWillStartLiveScrollNotification, object: nil)
```

Just place your function inside the `#Selector()`

Comment: I get 2 errors:  "Expected expression in list of expressions" and "Expected ',' separator". This is my statement: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector("resetScroller"), name: NSScrollViewWillStartLiveScrollNotification, object: nil)`. XCode wants to add a a comma between 'selector:' and '#selector()'.

Comment: #selector is an objc c type selector. If you have a function doSomething() in class ViewController you use #selector(ViewController.doSomething(:))

Comment: I found that rather than #selector, use Selector("functionName").

Comment: #selector is new since swift 2.2 and provides protection to typos, string based function names will become deprecated: https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/

Comment: This doesn't work when the user scrolls with a mouse wheel.